# Scaling colormaps with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have two surface plots, which I would like to have to same color for the same height. So, as the first plot is dark blue for f(x,y)=0, the right plot should also be dark blue for f(x,y)=0. However, the color dark blue is assigned to the lowest point of the plot. Thus, the color for f(x,y) in the right plot is a bright orange.

Sample source:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% first plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[surf,colormap name=hot,domain=-2:2] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% second plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[surf,colormap name=hot,domain=-2:2] {exp(-x^2-y^2)-exp(-(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I force the plots to have the same color for the same height?

Comment: Do the plot shapes look like you want them to? Are you trying to plot `z=e^(-(x^2)-(y^2))` or `z=e^((-x)^2+(-y)^2)`?

Comment: Actually the pictures above are not the plots of my example, the correct pictures can be found in the answer below. I dont know why Werner has modified my plotting functions. Anyway, I actually want to plot something totally different, the Gaussian function is just here to show what I am talking about. Also note that `z=e^((-x)^2+(-y)^2) = z=e^(x^2+y^2)`, so I do not understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, `(-x)^2 = x^2`, but that's not what I wrote. I said `-(x^2)`.

Comment: @Werner: Which version of PGF and PGFplots do you use? I get a different output from compiling Peter's code than the image you embedded, using `tikz.sty 2010/10/13 v2.10` and `pgfplots.sty 2011/07/29 v1.5`

Comment: @Jake: Perhaps you can update the image with the appropriate output, since I added it from a system still running TeX Live 2009. I had thought an image would clearly show the problem, but if the output differs greatly, change or remove it.

Comment: No need to change the pictures.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, PGFplots will stretch the colormap to span the whole range of `meta` values (which, by default, are the `y` values) of all the plots in the axis. In your case, you would need to set the range explicitly. You can do this using `point meta min=...` and `point meta max=...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% first plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[point meta min=-1, point meta max=1]
\addplot3[surf,colormap name=hot,domain=-2:2] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% second plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[point meta min=-1, point meta max=1]
\addplot3[surf,colormap name=hot,domain=-2:2] {exp(-x^2-y^2)-exp(-(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly!