# How to set the colorbar mapped to only one plot in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have two plots in a figure, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/hsv,point meta rel=per plot,colorbar]
      \addplot[mesh,domain=1:10,samples=20,] {20*x+10}; %positive value
      \addplot[mesh,domain=1:10,samples=20,] {-100};%negative value
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The colorbar shows both the positive value and negative, but I want the colorbar only shows for the first plot. How can I do this?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39150/124842

Comment: Thanks. Your comment solves my problem and my search in this site  didn't find this post